# Should the services and repositories be always singleton as they are always stateless?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

By the principle of REST, API should be stateless. So if each request has its required context, shouldn't services , repositories be always singletons and the same instance could be reused?

With this there would be no need for the framework, to wire up and create new instances again and again for every request.If they are stateless, then even in multi-threading there would be no problem.

So, what are the recommended practices in this context?

Spring framework is designed in this way too.

Comment: `then why it is encouraged to have transient scopes for Repositories` where is that encouraged? Clearly you have read something that says that - you need to share where you found it, so we can understand the statement **in its context**.

Comment: Generally speaking the answer to "should ... always..." questions is "no".

Comment: @JeromeReinländer Could you provide a reason for that? My only reason is this they should be stateless. So its safe to make them singleton.

Comment: @santosh For the general case: there is pretty much no rule without exceptions. For your case: I would have written an answer if I knew one. It is often considered a bad code smell as it may hide dependencies to use singletons, but I feel like this is more of an opinion and depends on usage.

Comment: @mjwills I have modified the question. The default scope is instance-per-dependency. In .Net core it is transient.  Even seen in few projects that I was working on.This article seems to recommend too, however I might be wrong raising question here rather than there. https://medium.com/volosoft/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-best-practices-tips-tricks-c6e9c67f9d96

Comment: @JeromeReinländer, I agree that singleton is antipattern. But SpringFramework's does have beans scoped singleton. As a matter of fact , in Spring its always recommended to have singleton. The main argument Spring brings on this is that services, repositories should be stateless. So its safe in multithreading environment and performance wise framework can reuse the same istance. I wonder why there is difference of approach.

Comment: @mjwills I dont have sufficient experience in .Net Core or even using autofac. Can I ask you what is the recommended way scopes for general services and repositories .

Comment: If you use reloadable configuration source (and `IOptionsSnapshot`), if your service is a singleton, it will not be able to get the new configuration values.

Comment: `The default scope is instance-per-dependency. In .Net core it is transient. Even seen in few projects that I was working on.` OK, that is a **completely different question**. And the answer to that is simple - the default needs to be safe. `InstancePerDependency` will work for almost all scenarios - sure it may be _wasteful_, but it will **work**. `SingleInstance` will **not work** for many scenarios - even though it is more efficient. As such, they chose a safe default - with the ability to choose a better option when needed.

Comment: `So, what are the recommended practices in this context?` The recommended practice is to choose the appropriate instance scope for your needs, as per https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html .

Comment: `This article seems to recommend too` I read that article, and it makes sense. What part of it is confusing to you? It has some good overall principles - including things to watch out for when using singleton. Honestly, your best bet here is just to **reread** https://medium.com/volosoft/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-best-practices-tips-tricks-c6e9c67f9d96 .

Answer (score 1):

Stateless stuff is great in programming. There are lots of benefits. However, sometimes it might be reasonable to make your repos stateful (as an example, simple caching or retrying logic, or buffering - depends upon concrete situation you're dealing with).

So the answer is: keep your code generally stateless and yet don't be afraid to inroduce state when appropriate.

P.S. There are smart FP techniques to deal with state in a stateless fashion. Checout Haskell's `State` monad as a classical example.

Comment: WHat about making the service that controller talks to for each request , singleton? As the service is going to be stateless.

Comment: @santosh, that's perfectly fine. However, it's far not the first reason, why you keep your code as stateless as possible. "Singletoning" could be seen as a nice bonus.